# Count column in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, sequence

Provided I have a  table like this in mysql:

```
userid, paymentid, datetime
blah, 123, 1/2/2011
blah, 144, 1/8/2011
foo, 151, 2/4/2011
bar, 178, 2,8,2011
```

How can I add a 'order' column, which is basically a sequence count per user, ordered by datetime?

```
userid, paymentid, datetime, order
blah, 123, 1/2/2011, 1
blah, 144, 1/8/2011, 2
foo, 151, 2/4/2011, 1
bar, 178, 2,8,2011, 1
```

Comment: [What have you tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: What do you mean? Are you wondering how to change the structure of your table or how to change structure and update it dynamically each time it's being updated?

Comment: I know at the core, it will be: 

SELECT @i:=0;
UPDATE payments SET order = @i:=@i+1;

But yes, just to change the structure - not dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT userid, paymentid, datetime,
        grpTotal AS `ORDER`
FROM
(
  select  userid,
          paymentid,
          datetime,
          @sum := if(@grp = userid,@sum,0) + 1 as grpTotal,
          @grp := userid
  from    TableName,
          (select @grp := '', @sum := 0) vars
  order   by  userid, datetime
) x
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8281a/3)
- [SQLFiddle Demo (*with ORDER BY datetime*)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8281a/4)

Answer (score 0):

So if you only want to change structure you can use this:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD order integer
```

Then you can create a "trigger" if you want to keep it updated:

http://www.sqlteam.com/article/an-introduction-to-triggers-part-i

Another way is to create a "view" where you dynamically calculate the order. You would then do all your selects from that view.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-using-views.htm